# Is there a way to find out what is in the latest build?

Tags: versions

The [release logs](http://www.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-267/) document the new features after a version has been released.

Is there a page which lists what of the [announced features](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aDoc/Projects) is already included in the [latest build](http://builder.blender.org/download/) ?

I can't wait to test Multi-view (stereoscopic) render and display support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update

For bleeding edge changes and latest bug reports, even typo fixes you can access these feeds as well

https://twitter.com/BlenderLogs

https://twitter.com/BlenderBugs

---

There isn't a pretty or detailed view like the release logs for the latest builds, one way you can keep up to date with commits is to go to <strike>[projects.blender.org](http://projects.blender.org/scm/viewvc.php?root=bf-blender&sortby=log&view=rev)</strike> [developer.blender.org](http://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/). As a new commit is made, it is updated there along with the revision number, files changed and or features added.

Additionally, if you are on [twitter](https://twitter.com/aiblender) or [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/114446066195540713841), Adventures in Blender posts about the latest additions or changes in detail with additional links at times. [For](https://twitter.com/AIBlender/status/339804984092794880) [example](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AdventuresInBlender/posts/HQptBcA3GQ4).

You can also now view the shortlog on [git.blender.org](http://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/shortlog) for a quick summary of commits/fixes.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such page (yet). Eventually a release log will be created in the blender wiki, but it will usually take some time before such an effort is started.

The best way to find out what is going on in the Blender code repository is to follow the commit messages in the commit list: http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/

This is a quite high-volume list, since a lot is going on.

Note that Blender code repository is scheduled to move to Git in the near future (but after Google Summer of Code 2013), after which you probably will find even more commits to browse through.